# Curl : Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: curl, openstack

I use the command below to get the token.

```
curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/tokens -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": "'"$OS_TENANT_NAME"'", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "'"$OS_USERNAME"'", "password": "'"$OS_PASSWORD"'"}}}'| python -m json.tool
```

After this i want to make a curl call to openstack keystone service.So i tried,
curl https://keystone:5000

But it thorws an error

```
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT
```

How can i make curl calls to openstack services?